# How to convert an integer into a Binary Array..

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone give the simplest solution to convert an integer into a Array of Integer representing its relevant binary digits..

```
Input  => Output
1      => [1]
2      => [2]
3      => [2,1]
4      => [4]
5      => [4,1]
6      => [4,2]

One way is :
Step 1 : 9.to_s(2) #=> "1001"
Step 2 : loop with the count of digit
         use / and % 
         based on loop index, multiply with 2
         store in a array
```

Is there any other direct or better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixnum and Bignum have a `[]` method, that returns the value of the nth bit. With this we can do

```
def binary n
  Math.log2(n).floor.downto(0).select {|i| n[i] == 1 }.collect {|i| 2**i}
end
```

You could avoid the call to Math.log2 by calculating successive powers of 2 until that power was too big:

```
def binary n
  bit = 0
  two_to_the_bit = 1
  result = []
  while two_to_the_bit <= n
    if n[bit] == 1
      result.unshift two_to_the_bit
    end
    two_to_the_bit = two_to_the_bit << 1
    bit += 1
  end
  result
end
```

more verbose, but faster

Comment: Nice.  Okay now I am convinced to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.  I want my log2.

Comment: +1 ... But: Don't forget to filter out the zeros, for completeness :)

Comment: Oops, forgot about the zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that uses Ruby 1.8. (`Math.log2` was added in Ruby 1.9):

```
def binary(n)
  n.to_s(2).reverse.chars.each_with_index.map {|c,i| 2 ** i if c.to_i == 1}.compact
end
```

In action:

```
>>  def binary(n)
>>       n.to_s(2).reverse.chars.each_with_index.map {|c,i| 2 ** i if c.to_i == 1}.compact
>>     end
=> nil
>> binary(19)
=> [1, 2, 16]
>> binary(24)
=> [8, 16]
>> binary(257)
=> [1, 256]
>> binary(1000)
=> [8, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
>> binary(1)
=> [1]
```

Add a final `.reverse` if you would like to see the values in descending order, of course.

Comment: Thanks Ray...Yossi suggested -> tap[] ..                      array = [].tap{|arr| n.to_s(2).reverse.chars.each_with_index {|c,i| arr << 2 ** i if c.to_i != 0}}

Comment: @Ray: yeah, the last one is the good (except a final reverse is missing?). Not sure we need to see the tries though ;-)

Comment: You're right @tokland, the tries were stupid.  Cleaned up now.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Integer
  def to_bit_array
    Array.new(size) { |index| self[index] }.reverse!
  end

  def bits
    to_bit_array.drop_while &:zero?
  end

  def significant_binary_digits
    bits = self.bits
    bits.each_with_object(bits.count).with_index.map do |(bit, count), index|
      bit * 2 ** (count - index - 1)
    end.delete_if &:zero?
  end
end
```

Adapted from and improved upon [these solutions found in `comp.lang.ruby`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/a8e4e2e860db9c45).

Some simple benchmarks suggest that [this solution](http://ideone.com/sJwqG) is faster than algorithms involving either [base-2 logarithms](http://ideone.com/Yav9H) or [string manipulation](http://ideone.com/9VikC) and slower than [direct bit manipulation](http://ideone.com/wQocY).

Comment: log2 version is faster for me. I think this will depend on how big the values you use it on are: how many 'wasted' bits are generated (this will also depend on 32 versus 64bit ruby)

Comment: @Frederick, good observation. Your new algorithm does beat mine according to Ideone's timer.